# Missing argument 1 for CommentsController::store()

Tags: php, laravel

Im making a simple blog with Laravel and I have some issues with the comments section. I'm passing the `article_id` trough the comments form but I get this error.

This is the Article View

```
<?php
 $comment = new Comment;
?>

@extends('layout')
@section('showArticle')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>{{$idArticle->title}}</h4>
        <p>{{$idArticle->text}}</p>

        <div class="col-lg-4">Autor: {{$idArticle->author}}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">Categorias</div>

        </div>
</div>

<div class="comments">
<p>Comentarios</p>

</div>

<div>



{{Form::open(array('route' => array('comments.store', $idArticle->id, 'method' => 'POST')))}}

          @include ('errors', array('errors' => $errors))


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              {{ Form::label('comment', 'Contenido') }}
              {{ Form::textarea('comment', null, array('placeholder' => 'Comment', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}        
            </div>

        </div>
{{ Form::button('Publicar', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}    
{{ Form::close() }}

</div>

@stop
```

The controller

```
public function store($idArticle)
    {
        var_dump($id);
        exit();
    }
```

And my route

```
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: which error is occured ? can you describe it ?

Comment: Please add the error to the post, not only in the headline.

Comment: Improved formatting, removed "thanks"

Answer (score 0):

Try it

Change the Article View

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => array('comments.store', 'method' => 'POST')))}}
{{ Form::hidden('article_id',$idArticle->id) }}
.......
.......
```

Change Your Controller

```
public function store()
    {

        var_dump(Input::all());
        exit();

    }
```

Comment: Man that was a nice solution. Works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for nested resources.

Change your route to:

```
Route::resource('articles.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

This will generate urls like:

```
articles/{articleId}/comments
articles/{articleId}/comments/{commentId}
```

Now you open your form as you did before (with updated route name):

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => array('articles.comments.store', $idArticle->id), 'method' => 'POST'))}}
```